# Login PHP con usuarios de MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas tardes y con respeto estoy realizando un proyecto escolar donde en un apartado debo ingresar en un login  con los usuarios de MySQL que cree, quizá no he buscado bien pero no he encontrado alguna documentación al respecto.

Por lo que mi solución fue crear el login, este manda 2 parametros que son **user** y **password**  al archivo **signon.php** que hace conectar a la base de datos de MySQL y **si inicio la sesion** pero me da algunas advertencias al ingresar a la pagina que tiene la información.

**¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar esto o mi razonamiento es incorrecto?**

> Notice: Undefined index: user in
> C:\wamp64\www\Control_Pedidos\signon.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in
> C:\wamp64\www\Control_Pedidos\signon.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
> failed: Host desconocido. in C:\wamp64\www\Control_Pedidos\signon.php
> on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002):
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Host desconocido. in
> C:\wamp64\www\Control_Pedidos\signon.php on line 6

Base de datos **"Control_de_Pedidos"**:

```
CREATE TABLE Producto(
    id_prod VARCHAR (8) PRIMARY KEY,
    name_prod VARCHAR(25),
    existencia INT,
    precio FLOAT,
    precio_venta FLOAT
);

CREATE TABLE Pedidos(
    id_pedido INT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_prod VARCHAR(8),
    cantidad INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (id_prod) REFERENCES Producto (id_prod)
);
```

Usuarios creados:

```
CREATE USER 'Capturista'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'capturista69';
GRANT INSERT ON Control_de_pedidos.producto TO 'Capturista'@'%';
GRANT INSERT ON Control_de_pedidos.pedidos TO 'Capturista'@'%';

CREATE USER 'Supervisor'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'supervisor69';
GRANT INSERT, ALTER ON Control_de_pedidos.producto TO 'Supervisor'@'%';
GRANT INSERT, ALTER ON Control_de_pedidos.pedidos TO 'Supervisor'@'%';

CREATE USER 'rootadmin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'soyadmin';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'rootadmin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Formulario **Login**:

```
<form action="signon.php" class="mb-5" method="post">
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label font-weight-bold">Usuario</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control bg-dark-x border-0" id="user"
            placeholder="Ingresa tu usuario" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label font-weight-bold">Contraseña</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control bg-dark-x border-0 mb-2" placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña"
            id="password">
          <a href="" id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted text-decoration-none">¿Has olvidado tu
            contraseña?</a>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="button">Iniciar sesión</button>
      </form>
```

Archivo **signon.php**:

```
<?php

$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  

    $conexion =new mysqli ('%', $user, $password, 'control_de_pedidos', 3306, null);
    if(!$conexion){
        die("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos: ");
    } else {
        // echo "Conexion exitosa";
    }

?>
```

Comment: a ambos input el falta el nombre ejemplo: `name="password"` y `name="user"` adicional puedes validar que se envien  tambien ejemplo: esto va despues de la apertura php `if(!isset($_POST['password']) || !isset($_POST['user'])) {header("Location: Login.php");}` y en mysqli es localhost o la ip de tu server no %

Comment: @Bryro Muchas gracias hermano si se solucionaron varias advertencias, ahora debo de buscar alguna documentación para el error  `Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Como te comento @Bryro tu problema esta en que se debe utilizar el nombre localhost o la ip donde se encuentre la bd, ahora mi pregunta es, porque estas tratando de ingresar a la base de datos llamada control_de_pedidos con un usuario y una contraseña enviada por un formulario? si esos datos nunca deberian pasar por alli, deberias de leer la documentación de como utilizar la funcion new mysqli https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php